# .Net Framework 4.5 doesn't show up in Visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have Installed .Net FrameWork 4.5 on my PC as you can see
[image]

But it doesn't show up in visual studio 2010.
[image]

What should I do to have .Net Framework in Visual Studio?

Comment: almost by design. Click more frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 has not .NET framework versions 4.5. 
You must use Visual Studio 2012 in order to support .NET 4.5.